# Post JSON to Jersey Request

Tags: json, api, jersey

I've spend half a day and got crazy to make my Jersey service accept and manipulate a JSON.

Here is what I'm doing:
In PHP using Zend Framework:

```
$client = new Zend_Http_Client("http://localhost:8080/api/");
    $data = array("city"=> "Paris", "zip" => "1111");
    $json = json_encode($data);     
    $client->setHeaders("Content-type", "application/json");
    $client->setRawData($json, 'application/json')->request("GET");
```

API method:

```
@GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)   
    public Response getAPI( Address addr) {
        JSONObject out = new JSONObject();
        out.put("city test",addr.getCity());
        Response response = null;
        return response.ok(out.toString()).header("Accept", "application/json").build();
    }
```

In a separate file I have my annotated class:

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;


@XmlRootElement
public class Address
{
    @XmlElement(name="city")
    public String city;
    @XmlElement(name="zip")
    public String zip;

     public String getCity() {
          return city;
     }
}
```

I get an unsupported media type error:

```
    Zend_Http_Response Object
(
    [version:protected] => 1.1
    [code:protected] => 415
    [message:protected] => Unsupported Media Type
    [headers:protected] => Array
        (
            [Server] => Apache-Coyote/1.1
            [Content-type] => text/html;charset=utf-8
            [Content-length] => 1117
            [Date] => Tue, 29 May 2012 17:55:03 GMT
            [Connection] => close
        )

    [body:protected] =>
```

What am I missing?

Thank you all,
Daniele

Answer (score 1):

I think you're over complicating this. Since your bean is annotated there's no need to create a json object for it. That's done for you.

```
return Reponse.ok(addr).build();
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, besides the output, I guess my problem is to fetch the json in input. This is what I'm struggling to achieve!

Comment: As long as your json input is structured correctly you should be all set. The marshalling and unmarshalling is done for you. If it's not working, try adding setter methods for city/zip but I'm not sure you need them.  Also, I assume you set up the @Path correctly on your service class?